# Why is the practice of consulting the dead detestable to God?

Tags: law, deuteronomy, sin, death, afterlife

Deuteronomy 18:9-12 (NASB):

> 9 “When you enter the land which the Lord your God is giving you, **you shall not learn to imitate the detestable things of those nations**. 10 There shall not be found among you anyone who makes his son or his daughter pass through the fire, one who uses divination, a soothsayer, one who interprets omens, or a sorcerer, 11 or one who casts a spell, or a medium, or a spiritist, **or one who consults the dead**. 12 **For whoever does these things is detestable to the Lord**; and because of these detestable things the Lord your God is going to drive them out before you.

Why is consulting the dead something detestable to God? Is there anything wrong with that?

Answer (score 2):

The text itself shows why God forbids that, and other practices. There is a list of related, forbidden practices:

> "There shall not be found among you anyone who makes his son or his
> daughter pass through the fire, one who uses divination, a soothsayer,
> one who interprets omens, or a sorcerer, or one who casts a spell, or
> a medium, or a spiritist, or one who consults the dead. For whoever
> does these things is detestable to the Lord; and because of these
> detestable things the Lord your God is going to drive them out before
> you."

The bit that should be highlighted in bold is the last sentence - **God would drive out of the land all those people who practiced all those evil practices.** A moment's thought suffices. How evil is it to make your children pass through fire in worship of pagan deities? Some pagan practices even required living children or babies to be burned alive in the flames of worship. That is why the prophet Jeremiah expressed the horror of what Israelites later began to do, having *not* driven out all the nations who did such things. God told him to:

> "Take along some of the elders of the people and of the priests and go
> out to the valley of Ben Hinnom. Then proclaim the words I tell you...
> I am going to bring a disaster on this place... For they have forsaken
> me and made this a place of foreign gods; they have burned sacrifices
> in it to gods that neither they nor their fathers knew, nor the kings
> of Judah ever knew, and they have filled this place with the blood of
> the innocent. They have built the high places of Baal to burn their
> sons in the fire as offerings to Baal - something I did not command or
> mention, nor did it enter my mind." Jeremiah 19:1-6 NIV 1987 ed.

God gave a 'package' of forbidden practices to Israel. That is because ***they are all linked***. Even if you don't engage in blood sacrifices, or casting spells, ***if you consult the dead, you have entered into the same pagan way of thinking and doing, which will lead you into other, related and equally forbidden practices. The link that binds them all together is the source of the power and knowledge at back of them*** - demonic power and knowledge. Once that source is contacted, the lure of deceptive power and secret knowledge draws a person in further. Don't take my word for it. Here are the words of one who was deeply into all such practices, until God delivered her.

> "P127 When I returned to England, my time was spent visiting covens.
> Many new ones were springing up, and it was important to encourage new
> members. White witches were swelling their ranks; therefore we also
> had to attract new members. We didn’t mention blood sacrifice – that
> would have caused fright.
>
> P210 In recent years witchcraft, Satanism, spiritism and other evil
> cults have trebled in their number. The occult has spread over the
> world like a malignant cancer. I cannot conclude this book without
> giving a sober warning against such grossly evil practices, for I have
> met young people whose lives have been ruined by getting mixed up with
> dark and evil things…
>
> …Satan sees to it that the searchers do get signs – evil signs and
> lying wonders… [P211] In Deuteronomy 18 God forbids all such
> practices, not because He is a cruel, forbidding God but because He is
> a good God, a kind and loving God. He knows these things are grossly
> evil. Therefore He warns us in love. He wants only the best for the
> men and women He made…" *From Witchcraft to Christ*, Doreen Irvine,
> David Cook, 1994 ed.

In her second book she expands further on this:

> P79  If people were only aware of some of the things which I have
> actually seen and heard, then they would certainly give serious
> thought to the consequences of occultism.  As a former Queen of
> witches I speak from personal experience. I am not a scholar or
> researcher piecing together bits of second-hand information. I know,
> because I have seen with my own eyes. Deut. 18…
>
> P80  There is much confusion. People ask me, “Why are mediums and
> white witches evil? Surely they do good works and help people?” One
> need only examine the source of their power. They do not derive their
> power from God, since they never make mention of Him, or of the shed
> blood of Jesus Christ. It is clear that their power, if power it be,
> comes from Satan. Many so-called ‘healings’ are short lived and the
> patient, in fact, in time becomes far worse. He then has to seek
> further ‘help’ and so is drawn deeper into the web of the occult.
> Mediums are often the one means of introducing people to the occult.
> Mediums claim to put people in touch with their dead relatives or
> friends, but as a former witch I know that demons are wonderful
> imitators and are convincing enough to make a person believe that he
> is speaking to one of his dead relations or friends. The Bible clearly
> warns us not to consult with those in contact with ‘familiar spirits’.
> These spirits are very knowledgeable and know much about the departed
> dead. They are able to imitate and thus deceive. *Set Free to Serve
> Christ*, Doreen Irvine, Nova Publishing, 1989 printing

**The answer to your question is** that it is not ***"just"*** practicing consulting the dead that is detestable to God - it is practicing ***any*** of those forbidden things, because **the source behind them all is satanic**, and Satan is out to prevent people coming under his loving protection.

Answer (score 1):

Let us reason from cause to effect:

- Man is unconscious in death.  Eccl 9:5, 6, 10, Ps 6:5, Isa 38:18, Ps 88:10.  Thus, the Bible very often calls death a “sleep”; Matt 9:24, Mark 5:39, Luke 8:52, John 11:11, 12, Acts 7:60, 13:36, 1 Cor 7:39, 11:30, 15:6, 18, 20, 51, 1 Thess 4:13-15, 5:10, 2 Peter 3:4, etc.
- The soul cannot think after death.  Ps 115:17, Job 14:2, 21, Ps 146:3, 4 “their thoughts perish, KJV).

Therefore, any attempt to communicate with the dead is either an exercise in futility, or more importantly, an attempt to communicate with something that is not dead and impersonating the dead and thus deceiving the seeker.

Necromancy was a widely practiced among the pagans as a form of spiritism.  Even if valid (which the above shows it was not) it is still forbidden because God wanted the Israelites to seek divine guidance from either God (via the prophets) or from the Scripture:

> Isa 8:19, 20 - When men tell you to consult the spirits of the dead
> and the spiritists who whisper and mutter, shouldn’t a people consult
> their God instead? Why consult the dead on behalf of the living? To
> the law and to the testimony! If they do not speak according to this
> word, they have no light of dawn.

This ban of necromancy effectively limits God's people to a single channel of divine information with no competing sources of data.  Put another way, the ban prevents someone from saying something like, "The Bible says this but when directly consulted my great-grandfather, he said this!" - or any other dead "authority".

Comment: It's intriguing how you can be so correct with some things, but so incorrect with others +1

Comment: @steveowen - then proffer ans answer of your own

Comment: I suspect that @steveown was saying that he strongly agrees with this answer (even though he disagrees with some of your answers to other questions).

Answer (score 0):

The first edition of the [Catholic Encyclopedia](http://traditionalcatholic.net/Tradition/Encyclopedia/Occultism.html) gives a great answer

> it is the attempt to work miracles not by the power of God, gratuitously communicated to man, but by the use of hidden forces beyond man's control. Its advocates, despairing to move the Deity by supplication, seek the desired result by evoking powers ordinarily reserved to the Deity. It is a corruption of religion, not a preliminary stage of it as Rationalists maintain, and it appears as an accompaniment of decadent rather than of rising civilization.

And Saul's visiting the witch at Endor is the narrative version of this same explanation.